# Does magento clean cl tables on it's own

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, indexing, ee-1.13

In the magento setup we are working on we've noticed some of the `_cl` tables are insanely huge, one being `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` is 0.86GB in size having 30,001,369 records in it

We know that the `_cl` tables are used by the indexer to know which records need to be updated and they are populated via MySQL triggers so that way plain SQL scripts that stuff that is indexed via the indexer isn't ignored

Now it seems strange to us that the `_cl` tables aren't cleaned out, we have the indexer kicked off via a cron job every hour or so so I am wondering: Does Magento clean `_cl` tables on it's own or should we have to do it?

Answer (score 7):

There is a cron called "`enterprise_index_clean_changelog`" to handle the cleaning of those tables.

It is configured via the admin at *System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Index Management -> Index Clean Schedule*. From there you can enable/disable it and adjust the start time and frequency.

Comment: Indeed. A shame that this is not enabled by default. Any idea why this is not enabled ? Does cleaning could make Magento skip some partial reindexations ?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, it does not clean these these tables. They are used to implement the materialized view pattern in MySql using the triggers.

I'm currently working on a site with multimillion SKUs in the database, so I should find out for sure sometime soon, but I've not seen them cleaned. If you want to do some code level exploring, take a deep dive into the Enterprise_Mview module.

Less than a GB does sound just tiny to me right now since my data set is so massive. ;)

Answer (score 0):

According [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento) it's safe to truncate the cl tables.

Unfortunately I didn't find an option to clean the tables automatically. So I wrote a little script which truncates these tables:

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_Truncatetables extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

public function run() {

    // if (!$this->getArg('clean')) {
    //     return;
    // }

    // Might wanna mofify this
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('./app/etc/local.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    if(is_object($xml)) {
        $db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
        $db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
        $db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
        $db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
        $db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;

        // Might wanna modify this too
        $tables = array(
            'catalog_product_index_price_cl',
            'cataloginventory_stock_status_cl'
        );

        mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

        foreach($tables as $table) {
            @mysql_query('TRUNCATE `'.$db['pref'].$table.'`');
            echo $db['pref'].$table." truncated\n";
        }
    } else {
        exit('Unable to load db connection');
    }
}
}
$shell = new Mage_Shell_Truncatetables();
$shell->run();
```